# Airflow experimental REST API FORBIDDEN 403 response

Tags: airflow

My system used to call the experimental REST API to trigger DAGs and everything worked fine.
When I upgraded from version `1.10.3` to `1.10.12` I suddenly receive this error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: ('403 Client Error: FORBIDDEN for url: http://airflow.server/api/experimental/dags/my_dag_name/dag_runs',
 ('request_method', 'POST'),
  ('request_url', 'http://airflow.server/api/experimental/dags/my_dag_name/dag_runs'),
   ('request_headers', {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '128',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
    ('request_body', b'{"run_id": "manual__2020-10-12T08:50:13.288911+00:00__version__69179146", "execution_date": "2020-10-12T08:50:13", "conf": null}'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Airflow version `1.10.11` [changed its default auth for the experimental api from default to deny_all](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/9611/files), which is more secure.
They made this change because the older behavior let anyone who has access to Airflow server to manipulate the DAG RUNs, pools, tasks, etc.

If you wish to make things work the same way as before (**not safe**), please add to `airflow.conf`:

```
[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

If you want to choose the safer road, please read [Airflow Security docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html)

Comment: why was this solution so hard to find